# Cannot invoke POST to OData inside the "onExit" event of a view in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to invoke a `POST` request exactly before exit or on exit a view.

The `onBeforeExit` event is not called while `onExit` called.

But the problem is that, any code for working with odata and sending a request to backend is not called while no any error happen. It seems it cancel all the requests to the backend while exiting.

```
onExit: function(){ 
        console.log("1");
        this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("ModelName").remove(
            "/objecttStatusLogSet(Objecttype='xyz',Objectkey='123')", {
                success: function(oData, oResponse) { 
                    console.log("2");
                    resolve(oData);
                },
                error: function(oError) {
                    console.log("3");
                    reject(oError);
                }
            });
        console.log("4");
    }
},
```

The problem is that I don't see neither `142` nor `143`. Just I see `14` in the console.

This code is working in general. For example when I call it in a button event handler.

Comment: ".remove" - it's an async AJAX call, so it will be executed once the request is completed. In your case it will be "142" or "143".
With regards to the problem:
are you sure that the odata model is still active and not destroyed in "onExit" method? You can set a breakpoint and check it.

Comment: Maybe you are right. It is async. But the problem is that I don't receive the request in the backend. I am sure the model has not yet been destroyed. Otherwise I couldn't access the `remove` function.
However there is nothing regarding the inactivation of odata in the documentations.

Comment: but "debugger" before the ".remove" call and check it's properties. I anticipate that "bIsDestroyed" is set to "true". So physically model is there and you are able to execute ".remove" method, but logically it might be destroyed.

Comment: So what do you suggest. I set a luck for my object in edit more. Sometimes users before releasing the object press the back button and object left lucked. So is there any other possible solutions?

Comment: Back button does not always mean that your controller will be destroyed (only in cases if back button leads to launchpad). But in other cases, the previous page will be reopened, which does not lead to destruction of the controller.
I'd suggest to track "onBeforeUpload" event (in case user closes the tab or browser window) and track the pattern change from the current page to any other one (via router).